# How to swap Connection String when publishing a project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-config, publishing

I can see that `Web.config` file contains two files:

```
-web.Debug.config
-web.Release.config
```

Inside this config files there is the following comment:

> In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the
>   value of  "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the
>   "Match" locator  finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" 
    connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

What is the `"Match" locator` ?
I already have a connection  String in `Web.config` So how do I set this up?
should the main web.config file  contain the production connection string or the other way around?
I'm looking for adivices from people that have done similar things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are using xdt:Transform="Replace" which basically replaces the connection string of our development DB and it works perfectly. See below:

Development connection string (in your case web.Debug.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=DebugSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDebugDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Production connection string (in your case web.Release.config):

```
<connectionStrings xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Which connection did you put in your Main Web.config, production or local

Comment: When I publish it still takes the local connection

Comment: Thanks I needed to set the solution configuration to Release before publishing

Comment: Yes exactly you need to change profile before publishing, I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

`Match(name)` means that the name of the `connectionString` in your case **MyDB** if it is same as in web.config that it will set the `connectionString` attributes to what you have in your `web.debug.config` file's `connectionString` when you publish the website.  A complete documentation can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). And a basic how to do can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).